# display widget checkbox selection on frontend

Tags: widgets, front-end, list

I create a widget for a custom post type that will display a list of post in the widget area. it works fine, i can select multiple posts and save the widget but i can not get it to display on the frontend.
**UPDATE**
so basically what i'm trying to achieve is list all the posts in the widget area with a checkbox (works fine), when a checkbox is checked it will show that post in the frontend, if checkbox isn't checked it will not show on the frontend. that s the part that isn't working, i get no coNtent output on the frontend
**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
    <?php class mm_location_widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
    // Base ID of your widget
    'mm_location_widget', 

    // Widget name will appear in UI
    __('Locations By Marvil Media Widget', 'mm_location_widget_domain'), 

    // Widget description
    array( 'description' => __( 'Locations Widget By Marvil Media', 'mm_location_widget_domain' ), ) 
    );
    }

    // Creating widget front-end
    // This is where the action happens
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $your_checkbox_var = $instance[ 'your_checkbox_var' ] ? 'true' : 'false';
    // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $title ) )
    echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

    // This is where you run the code and display the output
    //echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'mm_location_widget_domain' );

    // Retrieve the checkbox

    if ( $your_checkbox_var == 'checked' ) {
    $loc_id = $post->ID;
    $loc_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $loc_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $loc_address = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_address', true );
    $loc_city = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_city', true );
    $loc_state = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_state', true );
    $loc_zipcode = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_zipcode', true );
    $loc_phone = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_phone', true );
    $loc_direction = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_direction', true );


    // echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $loc_info .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
    $loc_info .= '<h5><a target="_blank" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h5>';
    $loc_info .= '<p>';
    $loc_info .= $loc_address.'<br/>';
    $loc_info .= $loc_city.',&nbsp;'.$loc_state.'&nbsp;'.$loc_zipcode.'';   
    $loc_info .= $loc_phone.'<br/>';
    $loc_info .= '</p>';  
    $loc_info .= '</div>';
    echo $loc_info;
    }
    // echo "</ul>";
    }; 
    ?>

    <?php // Retrieve the checkbox
    if( 'checked' == $instance[ 'your_checkbox_var' ] ) : 
    $loc_id = $post->ID;
    $loc_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $loc_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $loc_address = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_address', true );
    $loc_city = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_city', true );
    $loc_state = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_state', true );
    $loc_zipcode = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_zipcode', true );
    $loc_phone = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_phone', true );
    $loc_direction = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_marvilmedia_direction', true );


    // echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $loc_info .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
    $loc_info .= '<h5><a target="_blank" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h5>';
    $loc_info .= '<p>';
    $loc_info .= $loc_address.'<br/>';
    $loc_info .= $loc_city.',&nbsp;'.$loc_state.'&nbsp;'.$loc_zipcode.'';   
    $loc_info .= $loc_phone.'<br/>';
    $loc_info .= '</p>';  
    $loc_info .= '</div>';
    echo $loc_info;
    }
    // echo "</ul>";
    endif; 



    echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
    $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    }
    else {
    $title = __( 'Locations', 'mm_location_widget_domain' );
    }
    // Widget admin form
    ?>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'your_checkbox_var' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Locations:' ); ?></label><br/>
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'mm_location', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post )  {
    $option='<input type="checkbox" id="'. $this->get_field_id( 'your_checkbox_var' ) .'[]" name="'. $this->get_field_name( 'your_checkbox_var' ) .'[]"';
    //if (is_array($instance['your_checkbox_var'])) {
    foreach ($instance['your_checkbox_var'] as $posts) {
    if($posts==$post->ID) {
    $option=$option.=' checked="checked"';
    }
    }
    //}
    $option .= ' value="'.$post->ID.'" />';

    $option .= get_the_title($post->ID);
    $option .= '<br />';
    echo $option;
    } ?>
    </p>           


    <?php 
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance[ 'your_checkbox_var' ] = $new_instance[ 'your_checkbox_var' ];
    return $instance;
    }
    } // Class mm_location_widget ends here

    // Register and load the widget
    function marvilmedia_loc_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'mm_location_widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'marvilmedia_loc_load_widget' );
    ?>
```

Comment: Widget doesn't display at all or you can't get it to display how you like it?

Comment: @Zlatev the widget shows up in the frontend but the content doesnt show, so basically what im trying to achieve is list all the posts in the widget area with a checkbox (works fine), when a checkbox is checked it will show that post in the frontend, if checkbox isn't checked it will not show on the frontend. that s the part that isnt working, i get no cotent output on the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually knowing what you're trying to achieve I see the following problems:

- `$post` variable is not defined in your `widget()` method. Try setting it using `$post = get_post( get_the_ID() )` for instance.
- By the time you call `foreach ($posts as $post) { ... }` `$posts` variable is also not set. You need some query for this one I guess - `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`

In order to effectively catch such problems set `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` constants both to `true` in your `wp-config.php` file then you'll be able to monitor `wp-content/debug.log` for notices and errors. Good luck.

Comment: Zlatev thank you, basically what im trying to achieve is list all the posts in the widget area with a checkbox, when a checkbox is checked it will show that post in the frontend, if checkbox isn't checked it will not show on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
class mm_location_widget extends WP_Widget
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
        // Base ID of your widget
            'mm_location_widget', 
        // Widget name will appear in UI
            __('Locations By Marvil Media Widget', 'mm_location_widget_domain'), 
        // Widget description
            array(
            'description' => __('Locations Widget By Marvil Media', 'mm_location_widget_domain')
        ));
    }

    // Creating widget front-end
    // This is where the action happens
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        // $your_checkbox_var = $instance[ 'your_checkbox_var' ] ? 'true' : 'false';
        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if (!empty($title))
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

        // This is where you run the code and display the output
        //echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'mm_location_widget_domain' );

        // Retrieve the checkbox
        $args1 = array(
            'post_type' => 'mm_location',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $myposts = get_posts($args1);
        foreach ($myposts as $post) {
            $loc_info = "";
            $option   = false;
            foreach ($instance['checkbox'] as $checks) {
                if ($checks == $post->ID) {
                    $option = true;
                }
            }
            if ($option) {
                $loc_id        = $post->ID;
                $loc_title     = get_the_title($post->ID);
                $loc_link      = get_permalink($post->ID);
                $loc_address   = get_post_meta($loc_id, '_marvilmedia_address', true);
                $loc_city      = get_post_meta($loc_id, '_marvilmedia_city', true);
                $loc_state     = get_post_meta($loc_id, '_marvilmedia_state', true);
                $loc_zipcode   = get_post_meta($loc_id, '_marvilmedia_zipcode', true);
                $loc_phone     = get_post_meta($loc_id, '_marvilmedia_phone', true);
                $loc_direction = get_post_meta($loc_id, '_marvilmedia_direction', true);

                $loc_info .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
                $loc_info .= '<h5><a target="_blank" href="' . $loc_link . '">' . $loc_title . '</a></h5>';
                $loc_info .= '<p>';
                $loc_info .= $loc_address . '<br/>';
                $loc_info .= $loc_city . ',&nbsp;' . $loc_state . '&nbsp;' . $loc_zipcode . '';
                $loc_info .= $loc_phone . '<br/>';
                $loc_info .= '</p>';
                $loc_info .= '</div>';
                echo $loc_info;

                // echo "</ul>";
            }
            ;
        }

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form($instance)
    {
        if (isset($instance['title'])) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        } else {
            $title = __('Locations', 'mm_location_widget_domain');
        }
        // Widget admin form
        ?>

            <p>
            <label for="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_id('title');
        ?>"><?php
                _e('Title:');
        ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_id('title');
        ?>" name="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_name('title');
        ?>" type="text" value="<?php
                echo esc_attr($title);
        ?>" />
            </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php
                echo $this->get_field_id('checkbox');
            ?>"><?php
                _e('Locations:');
            ?></label><br/>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'mm_location',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

            $myposts = get_posts($args);
            foreach ($myposts as $post) {
                $option    = '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $this->get_field_id('checkbox') . '[]" name="' . $this->get_field_name('checkbox') . '[]"';
                $selected  = $instance['checkbox'];
                $arrlength = count($selected);

                for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
                    if ($selected[$x] == $post->ID) {
                        $option = $option .= ' checked="checked"';
                    }
                }
                //}
                $option .= ' value="' . $post->ID . '" />';

                $option .= get_the_title($post->ID);
                $option .= '<br />';
                echo $option;
            }
            ?>
       </p>          

        <?php
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance             = array();
        $instance['title']    = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
        $instance['checkbox'] = $new_instance['checkbox'];
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class mm_location_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function marvilmedia_loc_load_widget()
{
    register_widget('mm_location_widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'marvilmedia_loc_load_widget');
```

Comment: Hi @sacgro, welcome to WPSE! Please feel free to take the [tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour). Would you mind adding some explanation to your post of what your code does?